# How to update a broadcast variable on regular intervals to be used inside a spark SQL UDF?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am registering a new UDF with the refreshed Broadcast variable after every 5 mins.

```
private static void runScheduledThreadToUpdateBroadcastVariable(JavaSparkContext jsc, Arguments arguments, SparkSession spark) {
      try {
          Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  hashMapBroadcast.unpersist(false);
                  config.setAccountsConfig(arguments.accountsFilePath);
                  hashMapBroadcast = jsc.broadcast(config.getAccountsConfig());
                  UserDefinedFunction LogUdf = udf(new MyUDF(hashMapBroadcast), DataTypes.StringType);
                  spark
                          .sqlContext()
                          .udf()
                          .register(
                                  "function1",
                                  LogUDF);

              }
          };

          ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
          executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateTask, 1, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      }catch (Exception e){
          logger.error("Exception occurred : " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
      }
    }
```

Here is the definition of the MYUDF class.

```
static class MyUDF implements UDF1<String, String> {
        private HashMap<Long, String> broadCastMap;
        public MyUDF(Broadcast<HashMap<Long, String>> broadCastMap) {
            this.broadCastMap = broadCastMap.value();
        }
        public String call(String log) {
            return function1(log, this.broadCastMap);
        }
    }
```

The following application log is getting displayed when I run it locally.

```
WARN SimpleFunctionRegistry: The function function1 replaced a previously registered function.
```

After this, why is it then not using the newly registered function1 UDF passed with a refreshed hashMapBroadcast?